# WPF Binding: Fallback to value defined in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

How can a WPF color binding fall back to the default value?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```xaml
<TextBox Text="Some Binding"/>
```

Will produce a Textbox with some background color defined elsewhere.

```xaml
<Textbox Text="Some Binding" 
  Background = "{Binding Path=Status, 
  TargetNullValue='Same color as the Textbox above, please', 
  Converter=***}"/>
```

This textbox is supposed to change its color based on the status (which works fine) but for certain values I want the background to revert back to the color which would be used without the binding at all.

Additional info: I use these Textboxes in a resource dictionary.

```xaml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType=**MyTreeControl**>
    <Style.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate ***>
        <Textboxes from above/>
```

Thank you very much!

Edit: In the end I used @Mike's solution, which I find quite elegant.

However I was intrigued why this works while yesterday this didn't

```
<DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=Status }" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
              </DataTrigger>
              <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=Status }" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
              </DataTrigger>
```

So tried again and today it worked as well. Seems like WPF-magic to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is tricky, because any `Binding` you set on `Background` will take precedence over the value that would otherwise be applied.

What you need is a way to conditionally set a `Binding`.  @grek40's solution was on the right track, but the conditional logic needs to evaluate the *output* of the proposed binding rather than the *input* to that binding.

First, you'll need a converter similar to the one @grek40 proposed, but with the potential to drill down into another converter.  Note that this converter relies on your Status-to-Brush converter returning **null** when no color should be set.

```
public class IsNotNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public IValueConverter InnerConverter { get; set; }

    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (InnerConverter != null)
            value = InnerConverter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
        return value != null &&
               value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

And inside the template that declares your text box, you'll need a trigger that conditionally applies the `Background` binding:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <l:StatusToBrushConverter x:Key="StatusConverter" />
    <l:IsNotNullConverter x:Key="ShouldApplyStatusConverter"
                          InnerConverter="{StaticResource StatusConverter}" />
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
  <TextBox x:Name="_textBox" />
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Status,
                                   Converter={StaticResource ShouldApplyStatusConverter}}"
                 Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="_textBox"
              Property="Background"
              Value="{Binding Path=Status,
                              Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Binding.DoNothing was new to me, so I learned a bit about WPF. Thanks for that. Sadly it does not help me in this case. This way, when I select an element with normal status (converter returns DoNothing) the background color will stay as it is instead of reverting to the textbox default.

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you very much, @Mike. Just two question: Why does ConvertBack return DoNothing? Do I need to implement it at all? And why check for DependencyProperty.UnsetValue? I've started with WPF only recently and don't fully understand its purpose yet.

Comment: `ConvertBack` is an interface method; you _must_ implement it somehow.  I implemented it in a way that prohibits it from being used for a target-to-source value transfer, because there isn't one that makes sense.  You could write `throw new NotSupportedException();` instead.  `UnsetValue` is a sentinel value that, when returned from a converter, indicates a conversion could not be performed.  I treat it the same way as `null` in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I only ever used `throw` in an unneeded ConvertBack, so I had this in mind when wrote not to implement it.

Comment: Thinking about it again, throwing is probably a better course of action, as using this in a two-way binding is clearly an error that should be reported.

Answer (score 0):

> but for certain values I want the background to revert back to the color

Place this logic in your converter (since you're already using one).

```
public class MyStatusToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Status status = (Status)value;

        // maybe use a switch statement depending on number of cases?
        if (status == Status.SomeValue || status == Status.SomeOtherValue)
            return Brushes.Brushes.Transparent;
        else
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is exactly what I was trying to avoid. When I copy the default color into the converter and someone changes the general style, the converter will require modification as well.

Comment: copy the default color? does this happen during runtime? please clarify what you trying to do.

Comment: Basically I have a textbox which shows the status of my selected element. For certain stati I want to highlight the textbox. Say status 1 green, status 2 red. If the status is neither the box should look like the other textboxes. By copy the color I simply meant to write it hardcoded into the converter. This would of course work now. However if someone would change the style of the textboxes the status box would still get the hard coded value in the converter which would make it seem out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't explicitly fall back. Your best option might be to conditionally set your color only when you really want to set one for a status. This can be done with style triggers. Here is an example that does something similar based on a textbox text being not null or empty:

```xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- emulate some default style -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
    </Style>

    <local:TestColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<!-- ... -->

    <TextBox Text="a Status">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource colorConverter},ConverterParameter='Check'}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

The converter has two modes: (1) return True/False to indicate whether the status has a custom color (2) return a Brush with the custom status color

```
public class TestColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // the question doesn't explain the status type, so I use string.
    // probably replace string with your actual status type

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (string.Equals("Check", parameter as string))
        {
            return HasColor(value as string);
        }
        return GetColor(value as string);
    }

    private bool HasColor(string status)
    {
        return GetColor(status) != null;
    }

    private Brush GetColor(string status)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(status))
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (status.StartsWith("a"))
        {
            return Brushes.Red;
        }
        return Brushes.DarkGoldenrod;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
The trigger works fine for highlighting the respective stati. Unfortunately the textbox won't revert back to its unhighlighted background when I select an element with normal status.

Comment: @GrimmReaper if your question is fully answered, you should [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Otherwise feel free to ask for clarification or to wait for better answers.

Comment: If my problem was fully solved, I would have gladly accepted an answer. I'm familiar with this kind of forum from unity answers. I tried every suggestion and read additional information about those directions but my problem prevails. About asking for clarification: I pretty much understand the behaviour of the trigger (or Binding.DoNothing in the other reply). Since my "look normal" case is not specified it won't update. However if I specify it, I can't tell the box to use the default.

Comment: @GrimmReaper edited my example to be a bit closer to your status thing...

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, as the second setter for `Background` will always overwrite the first:

```
<!-- Set the background based on the level into the tree. -->
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataItem.Level, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBrushConverter}}"/>
<!-- Row is red if no live updates received for N seconds -->
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataItem.IsStale, Converter={StaticResource IsStaleToBackgroundConverter}}"/>
```

To fix, wrap in a `DataTrigger`, so the second setter for `Background` is not even evaluated if the value is `False`:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataItem.Level, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBrushConverter}}"/>
<!-- Row is red if no live updates received for N seconds -->
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataItem.IsStale}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding DataItem.IsStale, Converter={StaticResource IsStaleToBackgroundConverter}}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

This means that the first setter for `Background` will be applied, and the second setter will be ignored if the `IsStale` value is false.

### Appendix A: Supporting Source Code

Converter:

```
public class BooleanToBrushConverter : ValueConverterBase
{
    public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush DefaultBrush { get; set; }

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var booleanValue = (bool)value;

            return booleanValue ? this.TrueBrush : this.FalseBrush;
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            return this.DefaultBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

And this goes between the `.Resources` tags:

```
<colorBrushes:BooleanToBrushConverter x:Key="IsStaleToBackgroundConverter" 
                                      TrueBrush="{StaticResource RedStaleBrush}" 
                                      FalseBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" 
                                      DefaultBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
```

You will also have to define the colors, or replace them with a constant, e.g. `DefaultBrush="Green"`.